# trying to copy an Ansible playbook from my local machine to remote host. But getting bad permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to copy a playbook from my local machine to the host machine (EC2 Instance) but It says I have bad permissions, despite add my key-pair to `~/.ssh/id-rsa/ansible-benchmark.pem`.

`Ansible-benchmark.pem` being the key.

The code I run is `scp /Users/mohammedkhot/Documents/terraform-consul/cis-playbook/main.yaml ec2-18-170-61-4.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/ansible`.

I am trying to copy my `main.yaml` file to `/etc/ansible/`

I did also run `chmod 400` before trying to copy it but it didn't work.

This is the error I am getting

````
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/Users/mohammedkhot/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/Users/mohammedkhot/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
mohammedkhot@ec2-18-170-61-4.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line in the output is telling you what is wrong. You need more secure permissions on the private key file which resides on your workstation. The current permissions are too permissive.

Change the file permissions to read only for your user using `chmod`, and then attempt to upload the file to the remote machine.

```
$ chmod 600 /Users/mohammedkhot/.ssh/id_rsa
$ scp /Users/mohammedkhot/Documents/terraform-consul/cis-playbook/main.yaml ec2-18-170-61-4.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/ansible
```

Comment: Thanks I did that, but the problem still persisted, I had to change the permissions from both my local machine and remote machine to get the issue fixed.